# How to pull memo from a public key's historical transactions and save to an array?

Tags: horizon, transactions, javascript-sdk, memo

***Using Stellar's Javascript SDK***

## Goal

Output an array containing all the memos:
 `['324567567', 'anotherMemo', '239210923', '2349028509']`

This array will be used to check against a database and confirm transactions.

## Problem

I have isolated the memos from every transaction; although, the output is delineated by newlines. My attempts with `join()` and a for-loop are unsuccessful.

### My Code

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

const hostAccountId = "GDUBG6QT24UYGBIAKRIVDA776STGIFM4XMHTAYGHOSCR44JIKN64JDKG" // Load hostAccountId from database ("test value")

server.transactions()
    .forAccount(hostAccountId)
    .limit(200)
    .order('desc')
    .call()
    .then(function (page) {
      page.records.forEach( function(record) {
        if (record.memo === undefined) {} else {
          var memo;
          memo = (record.memo);
          console.log(memo);
        }
});
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

*Output:*

> 18446744073709551615
>   12345678910
>   Another Memo
>   Special Memo only
>   What does this memo say

#### Background

I am very new to Javascript and to programming on Stellar. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate an empty array with

```
let memos = [];
```

And add an element with the push method.

```
memos.push( memo );
```

Snippet:

```
  let memos = [];
  page.records.forEach( function(record) {
    if (record.memo === undefined) {} else {
      var memo;
      memo = (record.memo);
      memos.push(memo);
    }
  })
  console.log(memos);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works getting all the values into an array. The output shows the array building up--call by call-- until the last return is comprised of all previous iterations in one array. For example the first returned array has only `memo1`, then the second array has `memo1, memo2` and this builds until the last array is `memo1, ... , memoX`. I am trying to build off of your solution to output one array with all the messages.